# Server room near the transformer units

Tags: datacenter

Need to clarify what problems may arise from servers in the server room when a transformer station is at a distance of 10 meters.
thanks.

Comment: Generally none.  10m is plenty of space.  But do you know the voltages and power involved in the transformers?  Is the station indoors or out?  Is there a firewall (brick, concrete) between?  Are transformers oil or air cooled?  This questions is probably more appropriate in the EE section.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it...

No noticeable impact on my servers. I've had indoor transformer units nearby, as well as external. The worst was actually having a 480V transformer *in* my server room, two meters from the server rack. The worst issues there were heat and the inconvenient access for electrical repair/service.

Comment: I agree. Oil-cooled transformers are usually shielded anyway by the oil-tank itself, which is nearly always metal. Air-cooled by necessity has openings, but the fields rarely extend more than 1 to 2 meters outside the device. The very big ones (like 150 KV transformers in use by the power company) have a safety-zone around them (arcing-risc) that is usually bigger than the EM fields.